# Count unique values based on a COUNTIF

Tags: excel, excel-formula, unique, countif

I'm stuck trying to calculate the number of unique numbers in column A if column B has a yes. The formula should output a value of 2, as only numbers 1 and 4 have a Yes next to them.

[image]

Edit: Title, did read SCOUNTIF amended to COUNTIF

Answer (score 2):

Having Excel O365, you could use:

```
=COUNT(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A9,B2:B9="Yes")))
```

With earlier versions of Excel you could use:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(B2:B9="Yes",MATCH(A2:A9,A2:A9,0)),ROW(A2:A9))>0))
```

Which is an array entered formula so confirmed through a combination of the keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with 2 new columns :

- 1st one for creating a basis to count, it could concatenate all entries or only the one including a "yes";
- 2nd using countif formula to find duplicates. Only rows resulting with a 1 are unique.

Two formula used :

1. =if(B2="yes";A2&B2;"")
2. =countif($C$2:$C$9;C2) in the D2 cell