# How to COUNTIF but only UNIQUE values?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: example]

I have a dataset with a column with references. The references always follow the same format. "1-XXX-YYY". The XXX is always 3 letters. The YYY is always a number. Each XXX will have the YYY=001, and if there are more types of the same XXX, there will be a YYY=002 and so on..

I want to know how many refences of each type there are. But, if the the refence repeats itself during the document, it should only count as 1.

I've tried with `COUNTIF`, but it obviously doesn't work properly.

As you can see in the example, the XYZ reference is counted as having 2 different entries. But in fact there's only 1-XYZ-001, and it appears twice.

What formula should I use so that the XYZ in my example would show as 1, and the others would maintain its value?

I've seen solutions to similar problems, but in this one my count-condition is only part of the refence, and I think that messes up stuff like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63825251/count-unique-values-based-on-a-countif).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Count Substrings If String Is Unique

[image]

### Edit

- I guess somewhere at the beginning of learning Excel, one learns about the `COUNT` function i.e. to count the number of numbers in a range (array), one really doesn't have to use `=SUM(N(ISNUMBER(array)))` (used by me before the edit).
- One can simply use `=COUNT(array)`.

**Single Cell Formula (Spills Down)**

```
=TOCOL(BYCOL(SEARCH(TOROW(C2:C4), UNIQUE(A2:A11)), LAMBDA(c, COUNT(c))))
```

**Formula in `D2` (Copy Down)**

```
=COUNT(SEARCH(C2, UNIQUE(A$2:A$11)))
```

**Formula in First Cell of Count Column of Excel Table (Spills Down)**

```
=COUNT(SEARCH([@Type], UNIQUE(Table1[Refs])))
```

Comment: I ended up using your second answer. Thank you very much

Answer (score 5):

Another approach could be:

```
=LET(a, A2:A8,
     m, UNIQUE(MID(a,3,3)),
     u, MID(UNIQUE(a),3,3),
HSTACK(m,
       MMULT(N(TOROW(u)=m),SEQUENCE(ROWS(u),,,0))))
```

[image]

or if you want it sorted alphabetically:

```
=LET(a, A2:A8,
     m, SORT(UNIQUE(MID(a,3,3))),
     u, MID(UNIQUE(a),3,3),
HSTACK(m,
       MMULT(N(TOROW(u)=m),SEQUENCE(ROWS(u),,,0))))
```

Or as suggested by Vbasic2008, we can improve efficiency by using:

```
=LET(a, A2:A8,
     u, MID(UNIQUE(a),3,3),
     m, SORT(UNIQUE(u)),
HSTACK(m,
       MMULT(N(TOROW(u)=m),SEQUENCE(ROWS(u),,,0))))
```

Comment: If you first do `u, MID(UNIQUE(a),3,3),` then you can do the more efficient `m,SORT(UNIQUE(u)),`.

Comment: Added it to the answer

Comment: Ended up using another answer, but thank you for helping out.

Answer (score 4):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=LET(r,A2:A8,f,MID(r,3,3),u,SORT(UNIQUE(f)),HSTACK(u,MAP(u,LAMBDA(s,ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(r,f=s)))))))
```

Comment: I ended up using another answer, but thanks a lot for your input

Answer (score 4):

If you have MS 365, you can use this in `D2` and fill down.

```
=ROWS(FILTER(UNIQUE($A$2:$A$8),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C2,UNIQUE($A$2:$A$8)))))
```

or as a single formula in D2, which will spill down:

```
=BYROW(
    $C$2:$C$4,
    LAMBDA(arr,
        ROWS(
            FILTER(
                UNIQUE($A$2:$A$8),
                ISNUMBER(SEARCH(arr, UNIQUE($A$2:$A$8)))
            )
        )
    )
)
```

[image]

*Based on the comment of @vBasic2008, should there be no Match against the item in Column C, the formula will return a `#CALC!` error. If this might be an issue, please use the modification below which uses `IFERROR` to return `0` in that circumstance instead of the error:*

```
=BYROW(
    $C$2:$C$4,
    LAMBDA(arr,
        IFERROR(
            ROWS(
                FILTER(
                    UNIQUE($A$2:$A$8),
                    ISNUMBER(SEARCH(arr, UNIQUE($A$2:$A$8)))
                )
            ),
            0
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: There is an issue to consider: since you are returning only the resulting column, you haven't made sure that there will be a match so whatever `FILTER` returns, it'll be at least one row so the result will never be 0.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Did you try it? With the data I used, changing one of the items in Column C so as to ensure no match, I find the formula returns an error in that case. If an issue, that can be easily tested for using `IFERROR`

Answer (score 4):

Try the following, this doesn't needs <kbd>LAMBDA()</kbd> helper functions,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,MID(UNIQUE(A2:A8),3,3),
     b,UNIQUE(a),
     c,TOROW(a),
     SORT(HSTACK(b,MMULT(N(b=c),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(c),,,0)))))
```

---

If you need with header then,

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     a,MID(UNIQUE(A2:A8),3,3),
     b,UNIQUE(a),
     c,TOROW(a),
     VSTACK({"Type of Ref.","Count"},
     SORT(HSTACK(b,MMULT(N(b=c),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(c),,,0))))))
```

---

Comment: Just a quick headsup but you generated the wrong results for XYZ ;)

Comment: Oh yes, sorry i will fix that

Comment: Ended up using another answer, but thank you for your input!

Answer (score 2):

I see a lot of complicated answers. Hope this makes things easier for you:

```
=LET(
    data, A2:A8,
    crit, SORT(UNIQUE(TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(data, "-"), "-"))),
    HSTACK(crit,MAP(crit,LAMBDA(m, COUNT(SEARCH(m,UNIQUE(data))))))
)
```

[image]

Comment: I ended up using another answer, but thank you for your input!