# Using TEXTSPLIT without copy-fill-down

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

| Ref | Desired |
| --- | --- |
| 1-ABC-001 | ABC |
| 1-XYZ-001 | XYZ |
| 1-ABC-002 | ABC |
| 1-JKL-002 | JKL |
| 1-XYZ-001 | XYZ |
| 1-JKL-002 | JKL |
| 1-JKL-003 | JKL |

What am I doing wrong here? Why does `MAP()` not work with `TEXTSPLIT()`?

Formula used is `=MAP(A2:A8,LAMBDA(X,TEXTSPLIT(X,"-")))`

Comment: Are you working on different account here? This data looks a awefull lot like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77142008/9758194) recent question. If this is you, I'd advise you to work through a single account over here. OT: Would you need `TEXTSPLIT()` at all? I mean, it seems your data sits at a specific index within the ref-data. Would `=MID(A2:A8,3,3)` not work?

Comment: Even I had the same question. They looks like using two different accounts. And I am surprised why this solution was not provided in first place `=MID(A2:A8,3,3)`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya `MID` is a great approach, but we don't know if the first number has a fix length. It seems the OP is looking for splitting by `"-"`.

Comment: @DavidLeal OP would have posted if there were any anomaly, but it shows a clear pattern. At least if i post á question, i would post all the possibilities that can happen, at least i should i know how my data will be.

Comment: No. I'm not working on a different account. I used the recent question data as reference for my question. However, I still haven't got the answer for my question. 'How to know if a formula supports a dynamic array?. just by trail and error?

Comment: @santhosha if the linked question in my first comment here was not your 2nd account. How do explain the use of the exact same sample data? Just wondering..

Comment: I am not stuck with any excel problem. I wanted to understand how MAP works and came across the post that you linked. I used that to demonstrate my problem(read how MAP works).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Return Split by Index

```
=MAP(A2:A8,LAMBDA(x,INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(x,"-"),2)))
```

```
=LET(data,A2:A8,index,2,dlm,"-",
MAP(data,LAMBDA(x,INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(x,dlm),index))))
```

You could define a name, e.g. `SplitByIndex`, and use the following under *Refers to*:

```
=LAMBDA(data,index,delimiter,MAP(data,LAMBDA(x,INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(x,delimiter),index))))
```

to be able to use:

```
=SplitByIndex(A2:A8,2,"-")
```

anywhere in your workbook.

In this particular case, you could use the more efficient (*split by index 2*):

```
=TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(A2:A8,"-"),"-")
```

Comment: we had the same idea, :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `MAP` combined with `TEXTSPLIT`, you just need to take into account that when you split by `"-"` it returns two columns, you need to take just the second one:

```
=MAP(A2:A8, LAMBDA(x, INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(x,"-"),,2)))
```

but you don't need `MAP` to get this result, since `TEXTBEFORE` and `TEXTAFTER` work for arrays (but `TEXTSPLIT` doesn't in this context, that is why you need `MAP` or `BYROW`):

```
=TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(A2:A8,"-"),"-")
```

The above approach should be **more efficient**, since it doesn't require a `LAMBDA` Helper function.

Here is the output using `MAP`:
[image: output1]

and here using `TEXTAFTER` and `TEXTBEFORE`:
[image: output2]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. How do we know if a function works for arrays not?

Comment: Check the specification of [TEXTSPLIT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textsplit-function-b1ca414e-4c21-4ca0-b1b7-bdecace8a6e7), it expects a text, not an array, but it is not clear. Since the output can be a two dimensional array (when you split by rows and columns), you will get an array of arrays when the input is an array, so inside an array function will return the first column/row, which is not the case for `TEXTBEFORE`, `TEXTAFTER`. It is also something based on trial and error. Please consider upvoting the answer is you consider it is useful for you.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize you answered too (didn't refresh). I have a question though. You correctly used the additional comma to return the 2nd column (not row) of each split item. Why does it work without the additional comma used in my answer?

Comment: @VBasic2008 I know, about the comma you are correct, `INDEX` works for row/column array, so in this case, since it has only one dimension (columns), it assumes the second argument refers to the column, not row, so the second comma can be removed. Check the Remarks section from [INDEX](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) specification.

Comment: I tested it and you're right: *"When the data is in a single row, to return the 2nd item (column), you can simply use `INDEX(array,2)`. The same doesn't apply to a single column i.e. then it has to be `INDEX(array,2)`."*

Comment: @VBasic2008 it works in both direction for single dimensional array, for example: `=INDEX({1;2;3},3)` and `=INDEX({1,2,3},3)` both returns the expected result. You need both arguments for 2D-arrays when you need to extract the range intersection or an entire column

Comment: @VBasic2008 Microsoft over complicated explaining it in the documentation. If Instead of `row_num`, `column_num` they call them `dim1`, `dim2` for dimensions, it is easier to explain.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the sake of it some alternatives:

[image]

Formula in `D2`:

```
=PY(
    [x.split('-')[1] for x in xl("A2:A8")[0]]
)
```

And if you just so happen to be the same person on a different account from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77142008/how-to-countif-but-only-unique-values/77142059#77142059) post, then it appears you can also just simply take characters from their index:

```
=MID(A2:A8,3,3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the different alternatives.  Per MID's syntax =MID(Text,start_Num,num_chars), formula accepts 'Text' and it doesn't explicitly say it can accept an 'Array'. How do we know if  a formula supports an array ? . With this, we don't have to do any trail and error with MAP() and REDUCE()

Comment: @santhosha Array formula is native for Office 365, but there is no too much documentation coming from MS. [Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7#:~:text=An%20array%20formula%20is%20a,results%2C%20or%20a%20single%20result.), basically what is says is that you need to hit ENTER and try. Also [ExcelJet](https://exceljet.net/articles/dynamic-array-formulas-in-excel) has some documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Map will only spill as many cells in its arguments, so textsplit in this situation out puts three columns, whereas your data has one column. So you don't need map for this problem. Here are two solutions:

```
=LET(
    text, B4:B10,
    TAKE(DROP(REDUCE("", text, LAMBDA(a,v, VSTACK(a, TEXTSPLIT(v, "-")))), 1, 1), , 1)
)
```

or

```
=LET(
    text, B4:B10,
    remove, HSTACK(SEQUENCE(, 10, 0), "-"),
    REDUCE(
        text,
        MID(remove, SEQUENCE(LEN(remove)), 1),
        LAMBDA(u,v, SUBSTITUTE(u, v, ""))
    )
)
```

[image]

Comment: if the number of columns is a problem here then this formula should work right?. =MAP(A2:A8,LAMBDA(X,CHOOSECOLS(TEXTSPLIT(X,"-"),2))). We don't need HSTACK and REDUCE

Comment: This answer actually answers your question why it doesn't work. If you have a 1 column input in MAP it can only return a 1 column output. REDUCE is a workaround to make a different size output possible.

Comment: **Tip**: For a large dataset `REDUCE/VSTACK` has been proven an inefficient approach (several answers in SO related to this topic). For small dataset it is not relevant. Recommended to use when there is no other better alternative.

Comment: Second solution does not use reduce/vstack.

Comment: Related to your first formula: If there is no data or there is an error in any cell, your formula will result in a single-cell error. As David Leal already posted, the `REDUCE/anySTACK` combo is a last-resort option since it is far too slow (it's the *STACK* part that is slow). To prove this, apply your formula to only **10K** cells. On my (old) machine, it takes roughly 40 seconds for the formula to calculate. The *TBTA* solution will take less than a second while the other will take less than 3s for **1M** cells.

Comment: Second solution is virtually instantaneous. Even with an HSTACK (not a reduce/stack combo). Thanks for the info about the reduce/stack being slow.